# Edit inline datatable

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, inline-editing

I am using data-table which allows to edit inline. In that table there is one row with HTML(like span tag) tag. At the time of editing text-box shows the HTML. I am attaching images.

**Normal DataTable - Before editing**
[image: Normal DataTable - Before editing]

**After click on Edit button**
[image: After click on Edit button]

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: there is only one line to make this editable. $('#ID').SetEditable(); @SreenathPG

Comment: @PathikVejani, can you share sample code

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the text to a `var` then remove the cell text then append `input`

```js
        $(function(){
          $(".input").click(function(){
              if(!$(this).hasClass("typing")){
                var text = $(this).text();
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).append('<input class="input" type="text" value="'+text+'">');
                $(this).focus();
                $(this).addClass("typing");
              }else {
                $(this).removeClass("typing");
              }
          });
        
        })
```

```css
 .input {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td class="input">

        hello
        </td>
        <td class="input">
        test
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: it is not allowing me to type anything!

Comment: @PathikVejani, I don't get  what you mean